# Can Master's Thesis at a different institution be applied towards a PhD Dissertation?

Tags: phd, graduate-school, thesis, masters

I am a computer science student in the USA, and I could not find any information about this online.

Say one were to pursue a research based Masters, and they completed a Master's Thesis. If they later wanted to pursue a PhD (at a different university) would they be able to use the publications in their Masters Thesis as part of the PhD Dissertation in order to further shorten the time to graduation (beyond just the waived coursework)?

Comment: Are you envisioning a "stapler dissertation," which comprises essentially *n* papers pasted together to make a dissertation, of which your master's publications would be a part?

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- I never heard of that term before. Is this common in Computer Science in USA?

Comment: I have no idea.

Answer (score 3):

Not automatically and maybe not in the way you intend. It would depend on too many factors to make a prediction. Many, maybe most, doctoral dissertations in CS in the US are a single complete work, not a collection of papers. If the advisor agrees and the work extends the masters work in a significant way then it might work. But, as with all such scholarship, an earlier work can be quoted and cited but not "included" in a later one.

A dissertation need to be a new and significant work, even if it extends earlier work.

And whether the masters is at the same or a different institution probably doesn't figure in the equation, anyway.

Note also, though you don't ask the question, that in most places the coursework is there to enable a student to pass comprehensive exams. It isn't that it is "waived", but that the student has learned the material sufficiently elsewhere.

Some places might have required advanced coursework  but in many cases (including mine), there were two requirements for the degree: pass comps and write a dissertation acceptable to the faculty.

Also, having a gap in your education works against your specific plan, since others may have followed up on what you did earlier, leaving little yet to be done. You might have to embark on a different problem altogether. And an advisor might require that in any case.

So, it might work out as you'd like, but don't bet your career on it.

Comment: Every (European) declaration to sign when submitting a dissertation I've ever seen included a phrase like "The material presented here was not previously submitted in fulfillment of the requirements of a degree." Is this not customary in the US?

Comment: @Arno, yes, it is pretty  common here too, but the research can be extended, as I'm sure, is also true in Europe. But the OPs use of the phrase "part of" is a bit ambiguous.

Comment: At least when I did my PHD at Manchester in the UK the presentation of thesis policy said I had to either declare that no part of the work had been submitted for a previous degree, OR declare what parts had been submitted for a previous degree.